# System.SecurityException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: encryption, crypto

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted value.

Using the standard method from Crypto Class : Encrypt and Decrypt

```
public static String encryptValue(String customKey,String strValue){
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.encrypt('AES128',EncodingUtil.base64Decode('La73X9y4IU6xb+P1nyDvlA=='),Blob.valueOf(customKey.substring(0,16)),Blob.valueof(strValue)));
    }
    public static string decryptValue(String customKey,String strValue){
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.decrypt('AES128',EncodingUtil.base64Decode('La73X9y4IU6xb+P1nyDvlA=='),Blob.valueOf(customKey.substring(0,16)),EncodingUtil.base64Decode(strValue)));
    }
```

For encrypt I'm passing the

> customKey : RecordId
>
> strValue : String Value to be encrypted

It returns me a string which is a base64encoded blob

For Decrypt I'm passing the save encrypted string where

> customKey : RecordId
>
> strValue : String Value in base64encoded

it should return me the save value that i have entered before encryption

I have also tried using the Crypto.generateAESKey(128); in the method invokation but it doesn't work so as shown in the method I'm have Generated a key using the method and did a base64encode to the blob value and debugged it from execute anonymous and the using it in the method back by decoded to base64

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/263109/edit) your question and post your decryption code as well ?

Comment: can you add the whole code snippet?